# Animate a single shared element from UITableView to detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, transition

So I am attempting recreate something like this: 
[image: example]

At the moment I'm trying JUST to animate a single element in this case the right box which is is `UIImageView`.

Currently I'm having trouble with the animateTransition function which seems to incorrectly move my `UIImageView`. For one, it starts at the top left always and secondly doesn't move into the correct position. (It seems like the issue is with the X position).

Here is my code (it's pretty rough):

```
 -(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{

DetailViewController *toViewController = (DetailViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

TableViewController* fromViewController = (TableViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

UITableViewCell *cell = [fromViewController.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[fromViewController.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
UIImageView *cellImage = [cell viewWithTag:1];

[[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:cellImage];
[[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
[[transitionContext containerView] bringSubviewToFront:cellImage];

NSLog(@"FromFrame: %@, toFrame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cellImage.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(toViewController.headerImage.frame));


[UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
    CGPoint finalCenterPoint = toViewController.headerImage.center;
    cellImage.center = finalCenterPoint;

    toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

}];
 }
```

Would love some feedback. Also, I managed to find a solution using snapshots however I'm not sure they are the most performant way of doing this?

The other consideration is how would I handle NON shared elements?